# Deveria haver avisos ao incluir imagens nas perguntas, ou exigir reputação para adicionar imagens?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, perguntas, imagem

Eu acredito que este assunto deveria ser tratado no Meta do Stack Overflow, ao invés do Stack Overflow em Português. Mas, irei postar aqui.

---

Entre vários problemas que observo com novas perguntas, um dos maiores, e que vem se tornando mais frequente, é utilizar captura de tela (ou até foto) do código fonte. O uso de imagens já foi apontado em outro tópico, acho que todos concordam que utilizar um *print* do código é pior.

Obviamente, existem motivos legitimos para usar imagens. Acredito que tópicos relacionados à computação gráfica e tópicos similares creio que se beneficiem mais do uso de imagens, *mas não prints de código*.

---

**A questão é:** seria melhor (e seria possível) o Stack Overflow avisar para não incluir códigos como imagem no momento em que clicar para adicionar uma imagem? Ou, melhor ainda, exigir uma reputação minima para a utilização desse recurso, tornando impossível colocar imagens antes de atingir X pontos?

Comment: Reputação é complicado, pq ceifa possibilidade de uso legítimo (tipo os usos que você mencionou como válidos, que é representação de coisa gráfica de fato) por usuários novos. Mensagem seria uma boa, mas como é uma modificação "system wide", provavelmente teria que ser posto no "[big meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)", não só no nosso Meta (mas é válida a discussão aqui). Sou cético quanto ao sucesso da discussão (tendo em vista que tem avisos mais importantes que não conseguimos até hoje), mas... vai que "dá sorte" de gostarem dessa idéia né? Edit ago 2022: continuamos com o problema

Comment: De acordo com [este FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/401803): "*Some sites require 10 reputation to embed images in posts*" - Não sei se é o caso do SOpt

Comment: Não é o caso do SOpt, mas acho que podemos pedir para os CMs ligarem isso. Realmente o volume está complicado. @hkotsubo

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, tem uma pegadinha no FAQ (ênfase minha): "*Some sites require 10 reputation to embed images in posts. On those sites, **you can still upload images** using the below tool, but you won't be able to embed those images inline; you can only link them*". Então podemos até habilitar isso no site, pra ver se melhora um pouco. Mas o melhor mesmo seria a página de fazer pergunta dar um aviso.

Comment: There is indeed a customizable site setting for disabling image embedding by new users (i.e. if users without the ["disable new user restrictions"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege attempt to upload an image, it will just be displayed as a link). In addition, as @hkotsubo suggests, some of the guidance on the "Ask Question" page is also customizable, as explained in this MSE post: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/335251)

Answer (score 6):

**Situação depois de 3 meses:

Valeu como experiência, mas trocar embed de imagem por links de imagem não resolveu.**

Estou acompanhando o andamento de perto nesses meses. A solução de não permitir embed mas deixar o upload não resolveu o problema, continuamos com uma quantidade significativa de prinscreens (que agora aparecem como link - já ajuda indicar que não ficou bom, mas não evita o problema - em uma ocasião um voluntário prestativo transcreveu, mas não parte nada do OP geralmente).

Atualizei as tags da postagem para refletir a pendência.

Entendo que precisamos realmente de solução melhor, talvez não fazer o upload com pouca reputação (eu gosto mais da idéia de um aviso no upload dizendo que não é pra mandar código, mas acredito que não customizariam só para nós). É importante a comunidade participar da discussão.

Ou, ao menos, para passmos para [status-recusado](/questions/tagged/status-recusado) ou [status-intencional](/questions/tagged/status-intencional) um posicionamento no sentido de que não temos alternativa melhor no momento. Por isso é importante que a comunidade traga idéias e ângulos novos para tratar do problema.

Comment: Hoje existem várias tecnologias de interpretação de imagens (e até algumas IAs) que podem reconhecer o "assunto" de uma imagem. Ao identificar códigos, seja por IA ou OCR, adicionar um bloqueio na publicação, isso se o usuário não atingir aquela reputação.

Comment: @CypherPotato até gosto como utopia. mas na prática seria muito mais fácil e simples implementar uma fila onde as publicações começassem pendentes, no próprio sistema existente de filas - ex: OP tem menos que X pontos, a postagem entra na fila da comunidade para "triagem" (que determina se pode abrir para aceitar respostas) - seria útil para problemas em geral e bem mais realista do que uma IA só pra imagens. Mesmo mais simples, fica na utopia :D

Comment: Na verdade acho que piorou. Ou sendo cínico melhorou porque já se vê claramente que a postagem não está boa e depende de algo externo.

Comment: I've spoken with the developers... Apparently, disabling image uploads entirely on a site is not currently possible. If this community wants that implemented as a feature, someone should post it as a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange (if someone hasn't suggested it there already) and get feedback from the broader community first, in order to help the devs determine if implementing that should be a priority.

Comment: In the meantime, the guidance shown on the Ask Question page can be customized, as I explained in [this comment on the question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8745/deveria-haver-avisos-ao-incluir-imagens-nas-perguntas-ou-exigir-reputa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para#comment38409_8745). That's probably the best solution for now.

Answer (score 4):

Ajustámos a configuração deste site para desativar a exibição embutida de imagens carregadas por novos usuários (i.e., usuários sem o privilégio “[remover as restrições de usuário novo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)“, obtido com 10 pontos de reputação). A partir de agora, se usuários sem este privilégio tentarem carregar uma imagem, ela será exibida como uma link em vez da imagem ser incorporada na publicação.

Comment: Has it ever been suggested to completely disable the upload for those who have less than 10 points?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: I think it *might* be technically possible to disable image uploads entirely, but I do not think it currently set up that way on any Stack Exchange network site, and I'm not sure we would want to prevent image uploads entirely unless they are causing serious problems here.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: I've spoken with the developers... Apparently, disabling image uploads entirely on a site is not currently possible. If this community wants that implemented as a feature, someone should post it as a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange (if someone hasn't suggested it there already) and get feedback from the broader community first, in order to help the devs determine if implementing that should be a priority.

Comment: In the meantime, the guidance shown on the Ask Question page can be customized, as I explained in [this comment on the question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8745/deveria-haver-avisos-ao-incluir-imagens-nas-perguntas-ou-exigir-reputa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para#comment38409_8745). That's probably the best solution for now.